# How do I run tor in Saucy (13.10)?

Tags: tor

I am trying to run tor in Saucy.  In previous versions of ubuntu I would just go to the tor website download the program, extract it and then double click on a text file called "start tor browser" that was located in the tor folder. Now all that happens when I double click on that file is it opens the actual text but not the tor browser bundle.  Any one know how to get tor started in the newest version of ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download [the bundle.](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en)
2. Open up a terminal
3. Enter following commands:

   ```
   cd Downloads/
   tar -xf tor-browser-linux64-3.5_en-US.tar.xz
   cd tor-browser_en-US/
   ./start-tor-browser
   ```
4. Done

Answer (score 0):

I got the easy answer for you: open the terminal and drag and drop the `start-tor-browser` file into it. It worked for me.